# IOS - Handling Token Authentication in HTTP headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, http-headers

My organization has a number of different authentication methods used.  One that I have been struggling with has been our apps that use Oath2 that will be expecting the Authorization header to have the token information to be stored in the HTTP Headers.  I can manually put the Authorization header information for each request, but I would like this information to be automatically populated instead of manually adding it for every NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, UIWebView or [UIImage: imageFromUrl].  In Apples documentation for NSURLConnection class and NSURLSession it says that it will handle are designed to handle various aspects >of the HTTP protocol for you, including the Authentication header and they recommend not to alter this property, but it does not seem to get set for me.  At a minimum I would expect that for the NSURLSession object I should only need to set it once by accessing the sharedSession and adding the header info via a setHTTPAdditionalHeaders call, but it does not seem to hold the info on the next time I access the sharedSession.

I there something I am missing here or do I need to manually populate the HTTP Header on all calls?

**EDIT:**
Below is a code snippet showing how I try to set the header for the session.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id jSONObj = [defaults objectForKey: kTokenInformation];
[config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[jSONObj valueForKeyPath:@"access_token"]]}];
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
```

However, it doesn't appear that the token is present the next time I call [NSURLSession sharedSession].  So right now I have to do that every time I call the shared session.  I also am unsure from the documentation how you would handle apps that maintain multiple sessions which may each require separate Auth tokens.  Any thoughts what I am missing hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/NSURLSessionConfiguration).

For example, you could set up a singleton class that provides an `NSURLSession`:

```
// Session setup
NSString *tokenString = ...;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"X-Auth-Token" : tokenString" }];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
```

Now, every time you need to make a request you use your session:

```
// Send Request
NSURLSession *session = [[SessionManager sharedManager] session];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}] resume];
```

Here's a great tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394

Comment: Updated the question above showing how I do this today.  It seems essentially to be the same thing you runmad posted which I would expect to work, but so far no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the header name is correct and you're setting the value to exactly what the server is expecting?

Comment: I think I can see what I missed in Runmads example. He was managing the session in a SessionManager class. I had assumed that the "NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession]" call would always return the same session. The SessionManager is needed especially in cases where you may be have multiple sessions with different authorization reqs. I am still unsure what I need to do when I am using other objects, for example a UIWebView or UIImageView you would typically just pass in a URL.  For those objects would I need to instead pass in a URLRequest and populate the headers manually?

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming you weren't changing your auth header more than one time, once you have the token. And yes, for UIImageView and UIWebView's you will need to set them manually as well.

Comment: The issue was with the parameters, I had the wrong redirectUri.  Thanks for your help!